# Why my server request takes 28 Second to get response?

Tags: time, godaddy, latency, response-time

I have a Wordpress website on a Godaddy server having at http://kerala.letmeshare.org.

When I request to get this website this takes almost  28 sec to get reply.

Because of this I made a complete caching on both client side and server side. This reduced webpage request from 69 to 32, and from 1.2 MB to 200 KB. But the initial request time is remains same.

How can i Improve this? or is it the problem of Hosting Server?

[image]

Comment: Are you doing any reverse DNS on inbound connections? If so, is the server's DNS properly configured?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz , i dont have not much knowldge in this.i just created a subdomain, if its so how can i resolve? I read some where about Apache server will do reverse lookups.

Answer (score 1):

According to this brief article, here are some triggers that cause Apache to perform reverse DNS lookups:
http://betabug.ch/blogs/ch-athens/933

- *HostnameLookups on* somewhere
- checking of allow / deny rules with domains instead of IP ranges, e.g. Allow from www.example.org or Deny from example.org
- a rewrite rule with a condition like RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} www.example.com (the last two I found on this thread)
- update 2009-06-23 according to a post on a "simplywebhosting kb" , having Deny from none somewhere (this caused the problem to reappear for me one more time), apparently "none" is not a proper apache directive
- using %h in a LogFormat directive instead of %a (%h will give you the hostname, no matter what HostnameLookups says, %a will give you the IP address)

Do you need help locating your apache config (httpd.conf)?

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please provide content **here** and then link elsewhere for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Content now provided here. Is the answer technically wrong? Or is it typical to mod down on style alone? Trying to learn the culture around here.

Comment: I did not downvote on style. I down voted due to it being a non-answer. What happens when that link goes dead? Then your "answer" becomes worthless.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Will now make a habit of creating self-supporting answers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Excellent. I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

you could use http://yslow.org/ to find out where the hang up is .... ether in network dns php or somewhere else

Comment: YSlow won't give him any more information about the initial request, which is the bit that is taking 28 seconds.